# Jenkins testlink plugin FATAL: Error verifying developer key: Failed to parse server's response: Content is not allowed in prolog

Tags: jenkins-plugins

> br.eti.kinoshita.testlinkjavaapi.util.TestLinkAPIException: Error
>   verifying developer key:
>
> > Failed to parse server's response: Content is not allowed in prolog.
> >         at
> >     br.eti.kinoshita.testlinkjavaapi.MiscService.checkDevKey(MiscService.java:66)
> >         at
> >     br.eti.kinoshita.testlinkjavaapi.TestLinkAPI.(TestLinkAPI.java:162)
> >         at
> >     hudson.plugins.testlink.TestLinkBuilder.getTestLinkSite(TestLinkBuilder.java:241)
> >         at
> >     hudson.plugins.testlink.TestLinkBuilder.perform(TestLinkBuilder.java:134)
> >         at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:19)
> >         at
> >     hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:717)
> >         at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:199)  at
> >     hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:160)     at
> >     hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:499)
> >         at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1488)  at
> >     hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)     at
> >     hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
> >         at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:236) Caused by:
> >     org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClientException: Failed to parse
> >     server's response: Content is not allowed in prolog.    at
> >     org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcStreamTransport.readResponse(XmlRpcStreamTransport.java:188)
> >         at
> >     org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcStreamTransport.sendRequest(XmlRpcStreamTransport.java:156)
> >         at
> >     org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcHttpTransport.sendRequest(XmlRpcHttpTransport.java:143)
> >         at
> >     org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcSunHttpTransport.sendRequest(XmlRpcSunHttpTransport.java:69)
> >         at
> >     org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClientWorker.execute(XmlRpcClientWorker.java:56)
> >         at
> >     org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:167)
> >         at
> >     org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:158)
> >         at
> >     org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:147)
> >         at
> >     br.eti.kinoshita.testlinkjavaapi.BaseService.executeXmlRpcCall(BaseService.java:90)
> >         at
> >     br.eti.kinoshita.testlinkjavaapi.MiscService.checkDevKey(MiscService.java:62)
> >         ... 12 more Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1;
> >     columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.

Comment: now i am facing problem with jenkins tset link plug injenkins test plugin "unable to pass test cases to the test link plugin"

Comment: then go ahead and ask a new -- real -- question. We're looking forward to it.